# How do install security updates on an Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I see the following notices displayed on login:

```
   __|  __|_  )
   _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
  ___|\___|___|

  See /usr/share/doc/system-release/ for latest release notes.
  There are 30 security update(s) out of 39 total update(s) available
```

How do I install these updates on my machine?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As outlined in section *Security Updates* within [Amazon Linux AMI Basics](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonLinuxAMIBasics.html), *Amazon Linux AMIs are configured to download and install security updates at launch time*, i.e. *If you do not need to preserve data or customizations on your running Amazon Linux AMI instances, you can simply relaunch new instances with the latest updated Amazon Linux AMI* (see section *Product Life Cycle* for details).

This currently includes only *Critical or Important security updates* though, see the AWS team's response to [Best practices for Amazon Linux image security updates](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=314110&#314110):

> The default on Amazon Linux AMI is to install any Critical or
>   Important security updates on launch. This is a function of cloud-init
>   and be modified in cloud.cfg on the box or by passing in user-data.
>   This is why you see some security updates still available at launch.

Consequently, if you want to install all security updates or indeed *need to preserve data or customizations on your running Amazon Linux AMI instances, you can maintain those instances through the Amazon Linux AMI yum repositories*, i.e. you need to facilitate the regular [Yum](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum) update mechanism as outlined for the [yum-security](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum-security) plugin:

```
# yum update --security
```

Comment: +1 for the `--security` flag. Never noticed this after a couple of years of using yum, even after using `man yum` several times…

Comment: What do you do if you're running an ubuntu AMI?

Comment: @Greg Ubuntu uses unattended-upgrades to manage automatic security updates. (NOTE the command to run it is update the singular and the package name is plural)
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
sudo unattended-upgrade

Answer (score 28):

Please note: This does **not** work if *only* security updates are selected, due to the fact that [security updates are not properly flagged in centos and amazon linux](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=51300). This may be a matter of Redhat making security a paid feature which, if I'm being frank, is bullshit.
For this to work you must update the yum-cron config file to install all updates. This makes security updates less likely to run reliably which makes everyone less secure.

```
update_cmd = default
```

Amazon Linux runs updates when the host boots for the first time.
**If you plan to have hosts up long-term** you may also want to enable automatic security updates. I recommend using yum-cron:

```
sudo yum install yum-cron
```

The config file is here: (you probably want to just run security updates)

```
/etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
```

You can then enable yum-cron like so:

```
sudo service yum-cron start
```

edit from a useful comment below:
"If you're creating/destroying instances with an auto-scaling group, etc, the command should be something like "sudo yum update -y" in user data."

Comment: Don't forget to use this to run at boot-time `chkconfig yum-cron on`

Comment: Does this actually work. I tried to add this to user data, the provision fails. I think it fails at `yum -y update` step.

Comment: yum-cron is not for user data - it's for instances that are long-running. If you're creating/destroying instances with an auto-scaling group, etc, the command should be something like "sudo yum update --security -y" in user data.

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 has switched to systemd, so the command is now `systemctl enable yum-cron`

Comment: Don't forget `systemctl start yum-cron.service`

Comment: note that if you use yum-cron to install only security updates, no updates run at all.
https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=51300

Answer (score 6):

The answer above is correct, here are the 4 commands you can copy and paste to run:

```
# Install the package yum-cron
sudo yum install yum-cron -y
# Change the config file /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf and modify the line apply_updates from no to yes
sudo sed -i "s/apply_updates = no/apply_updates = yes/" /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
# Enable the yum-cron service to start automatically upon system boot
sudo systemctl enable yum-cron
# Start the yum-cron service now
sudo systemctl start yum-cron
```

These commands also work on Red Hat 7, CentOS 7

If you are running as the root user you can simply run the commands without sudo:

```
yum install yum-cron -y
sed -i "s/apply_updates = no/apply_updates = yes/" /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
systemctl enable yum-cron
systemctl start yum-cron
```

For more information see https://linuxize.com/post/configure-automatic-updates-with-yum-cron-on-centos-7/
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-setup-automatic-security-updates-on-centos-7/

Comment: enable saves you from doing it every restart